# QQ Plot for Poisson Distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've been trying to make a QQ plot in python for a poisson distribution. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats
pois = np.random.poisson(2.5, 100)  #creates random Poisson distribution with mean = 2.5
fig =sm.qqplot(pois, stats.poisson, line = 's')
plt.show()
```

Whenever I do this, I get "AttributeError: 'poisson_gen' object has no attribute 'fit'"

When googling that error, I found a lot of people saying that there is no Poisson.fit available. I'm pretty sure that the qqplot function is calling Poisson.fit. Does this mean that the qqplot function will not work with the Poisson distribution? If the qqplot function does not work with Poisson distributions, how would you recommend generating this plot? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: When you check the docs of `np.ranodm.poisson`, the first sentence says `Draw samples from a Poisson distribution.` What you want is probably `scipy.stats.poisson`

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested: pois =poisson.rvs(2.5, size=1000), but I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the comment. The actual problem is that discrete functions  in scipy do not have a `.fit()` method and therefore cannot be used in statsmodels' `qqplot` function. I'll have to check why that is, though.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2184

Comment: Will the QQ function work if there is no .fit() method for the distribution? (This is what I thought the problem might be.) Is there another way I can make a QQ plot if so?

Comment: no, the statsmodels implementation expects a `fit` method, therefore the error. But a qqplot is just plotting the quantiles of the (true?) distribution against the sample quantiles. It's probably not very difficult to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. The following seemed to work for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
data=np.random.poisson(2.5, 100)
stats.probplot(data, dist='poisson', sparams=(2.5,), plot=plt)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the end of 2022, and this is still a thing. I noticed that the statsmodels qqplots can accept frozen scipy distributions, which are not fit and thus do not throw the error for discrete distributions.

```
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 10
test_array = stats.poisson.rvs(mu=mu, size=10000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
ax.set_title("Poisson vs Poisson Example Q-Q Plot", fontsize=14)
test_mu = np.mean(test_array)
qdist = stats.poisson(test_mu)
sm.qqplot(test_array, dist=qdist, line="45", ax=ax)

fig.set_tight_layout(True)
plt.savefig('poisson_qq_ex.png')
plt.close()
```

[Example Q-Q plot using StatsModels with discrete Poisson distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAXrp.png)